# How to pull specific columns from a Wikipedia table using python/Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I've really been stumped for a while on this.

Link to table = https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Manchester_United_F.C._seasons

I want to pull the data in the columns highlighed in red below

[image]

And put it in a pandas dataframe like this

[image]

Here is my code

```
import urllib.request
url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Manchester_United_F.C._seasons"
page = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "lxml")
# print(soup.prettify())


my_table = soup.find('table', {'class':'wikitable sortable'})

season = []
data = []
for row in my_table.find_all('tr'):
    s = row.find('th')
    season.append(s)
    d = row.find('td')
    data.append(d)


import pandas as pd
c = {'Season': season, 'Data': data}
df = pd.DataFrame(c)

df
```

Heres's my output. I'm completely lost on how to get to the simple 5 column table above. Thanks
[image]

Comment: You may want to read answers in [this post](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/228969/python-web-scraper-to-download-table-of-transistor-counts-from-wikipedia/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there, though you don't really need beautifulsoup for that; just pandas.

Try this:

```
url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Manchester_United_F.C._seasons"
resp = requests.get(url)

tables = pd.read_html(resp.text)

target = tables[2].iloc[:,[0,2,3,4,5]]
target
```

Output:

```
    Season      P       W       D       L        
    Season      League  League  League  League   
0   1886–87     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN      
1   1888–89[9]  12      8       2       2        
2   1889–90     22      9       2       11
```

etc. And you can take it from there.